# Пропадает одна строка mySQL при выборке через Foreach

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach

Есть следующий фрагмент кода. Он должен брать значения столбца из базы mySQL и заносить в `list`:

```
...
Query.CommandText = "SELECT City_name FROM City";
MySqlDataReader MyDataReader;
MyDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader();
while (MyDataReader.Read())
{
    List<string> str = new List<string>();

    var test1 = MyDataReader.GetString(0); //обратите внимание на эту переменную

    foreach (var i in MyDataReader)
        {
            var test2 = MyDataReader.GetString(0);//test2 не совпадает с test1
            str.Add(MyDataReader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
```

Но значения заносятся со "второго". Как только программа входит в цикл `MyDataReader.GetString(0)` изменяется на следующее значение. С чем это связано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlDataReader поддерживает два подхода к чтению:

- вызовами Read в цикле - каждый такой вызов проматывапет ридер на следующую строку.
- перебором в foreach - где каждая итерация foreach проматывает ридер на одну строку.

Вы зачем-то  используете оба способа одновременно. Вызов Read в while вычитывает и делает доступной первую строку. foreach вычитывает и делает доступными внутри себя остальные строки. По сути у вас сейчас написано следующее:

```
while (MyDataReader.Read())
{
    List<string> str = new List<string>();

    var test1 = MyDataReader.GetString(0); //обратите внимание на эту переменную
    while (MyDataReader.Read())
    {
        var test2 = MyDataReader.GetString(0);//test2 не совпадает с test1
        str.Add(MyDataReader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

Или уберите while, или уберите foreach + объявите str до цикла while.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!